# Override NoopAnimationsModule for MatProgressSpinner

Tags: angular, angular-material

For the past couple of days I've been trying to use the mat-spinner and it never animates. From reading the documentation it states

> _forceAnimations: boolean
>   Whether the animations should be force to be enabled, ignoring if the current environment is using NoopAnimationsModule.

Google I found a post on another site where someone asked the same kind of question but this was the response
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12581

> Closing as this is not an @Input() on MatProgressSpinner. Additionally, all underscore prefixed properties and attributes within Angular Material are for internal use and not considered part of the public API.

The project I'm on does import the NoopAnimationsModule. So if a project imports this library how do you override it to allow for certain animations to occur? or how do I set the _forceAnimations: boolean to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what the [issue comment](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12581#issuecomment-411611538) says - provide `MatProgressSpinnerDefaultOptions` with the desired value. In the module that uses the spinner (or parent):

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: MAT_PROGRESS_SPINNER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: {
      _forceAnimations: true,
      diameter: 100, // that's default
      strokeWidth: 10, // that's default
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Being new to TS and Angular I had no idea what they were saying to do in their comment "Oh sorry, I misunderstood that I had to provide a MAT_PROGRESS_SPINNER_DEFAULT_OPTIONS to be able to use this attribute." Your post clarified what I needed, and how I needed to write the solution in the code.

Comment: I understand. Angular world is quite complicated.